# Travel Application Airport code returns City,Country

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to develop an travel application.I would like to submit  the Airport code and get back the Country,City, along with the weather of that particular space.Is there an API out in the market that will help me in doing that???Or is there some other way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one for the city/country: http://airportcode.riobard.com/about

and this question has good info about weather: [Weather API - Provides "About to..." Information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577503/weather-api-provides-about-to-information)

Here's a sample piece of code that accepts the text from 'inputTextField' and outputs the location to 'outputLabel'

```
-(IBAction)getCity{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://airportcode.riobard.com/airport/%@?fmt=json",self.inputTextField.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
const char *convert = [response UTF8String];
NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
NSDictionary *airport = [responseString JSONValue];
self.outputLabel.text=[airport objectForKey:@"location"];
}
```

Comment: I have couple of questions...Where I put that in my application?I am new in Xcode...I have worked with xml parser in android....have very little idea about Iphone

Comment: you'll make an NSURLConnection to the service and then parse the results. There is NSXMLParser, or things like SBJSON, JSONKit, etc. For the connection, lots of people seem to like ASIHTTPRequest, but I haven't used it myself. I'm guessing you'll make the request by attaching that IBAction method to some button, and will accept the .text of some UITextField as the variable

Comment: Can anyone elaborate in doing it??I am using Yazlios framework...how to add this into my page?i have a button and a textbox.clicking on the button will generate the result on the textbox

Comment: I added some sample code...this example uses SBJSON so you may need to tweak the JSONValue line for Yajlios syntax